# How to uploading of file with out browse in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload some files without browse button, i just wanna have a fixed path and upload button, can anyone help me out, i think this is possible in asp.net

Comment: Please could you add more to your question such as perhaps linking to information regarding the working example in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for a website to specify which file the user's browser should upload. This would be a dangerous security risk as the user might not notice the file selection.

Comment: the user specifies the path, but the path is fixed always

Comment: If the page reloads, then the form resets and the user (effectively) hasn't specified it.